The AWS SAM common layer can't find the modules
I have the follow directory structure:
common =>
         __init__.py
         common.py
customer =>
         app.py
template.yaml

My template looks like this:
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: '2010-09-09'
Transform: 'AWS::Serverless-2016-10-31'

Resources:
  CommonLayer:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::LayerVersion
    Properties:
      LayerName: common-layer
      Description: Common code for multiple Lambda functions
      ContentUri: common/
      CompatibleRuntimes:
        - python3.11

  CustomerFunction:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Function
    Properties:
      Handler: app.lambda_handler
      Runtime: python3.11
      CodeUri: customer/
      MemorySize: 128
      Timeout: 30
      Environment:
        Variables:
          LOG_LEVEL: INFO
      Layers:
        - !Ref CommonLayer
      Events:
        CustomerApi:
          Type: Api
          Properties:
            Path: /customer/{customer_id}
            Method: get

.....
Outputs:
  CustomerApiEndpoint:
    Description: "API Gateway endpoint URL for GET /customer/{customer_id}"
    Value: !Sub "https://${ServerlessRestApi}.execute-api.${AWS::Region}.amazonaws.com/Prod/customer/{customer_id}"
    Export:
      Name: CustomerApiEndpoint

Just to test I made a simpler version of get_customer in common (final reads from database etc)
as follows:
def get_customer(customer_id):
    # Hard-coded customer object
    return {
        "customer_id": customer_id,
        "firstname": "John",
        "surname": "Doe",
        "msisdn": "0696542321"
    }

when I run sam build and sam local start-api and call http://127.0.0.1:3000/customer/1
I am getting:
[ERROR] Runtime.ImportModuleError: Unable to import module 'app': No module named 'common'

In my app.py I have:
import json
import logging
from common import common

# Set up logging
LOG_LEVEL = "INFO"
logging.basicConfig(level=LOG_LEVEL)
logger = logging.getLogger()


def lambda_handler(event, context):
    try:
        logger.info("Received event: %s", json.dumps(event))

        # Extract customer_id from path parameters
        customer_id = int(event['pathParameters']['customer_id'])

        # Get customer details from common code
        customer = common.get_customer(customer_id)
        return {
            'statusCode': 200,
            'body': json.dumps(customer)
        }

    except Exception as e:
        logger.error("Error processing request: %s", str(e))
        return {
            'statusCode': 500,
            'body': json.dumps({'message': 'Internal Server Error'})
        }

Please help resolve this

I can see that after sam build it does not create the CommonLayer under .aws-sam/build so the error makes sense but not why it doesn't build irt correctly

Have you tried removing the "/" from ContentUri? My setup looks similar to yours and my layer is available in .aws-sam/build/
